# Как упаковать стороний python3 модуль в rpm пакет для CentOS 7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, rpm

Я написал python3 модуль который использует следующие сторонние модули:

jinja2,
requests,
ipaddress,
datetime,

Для своего модуля я составил .spec файл:

```
%global srcname netlord

Name:           netlord
Version:        0.1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Network administration module

License:        None
URL:            None
Source0:        SOURCES.tar.gz

BuildArch:      noarch
BuildRequires:  python3-devel
#BuildRequires:  python3dist(jinja2)
#BuildRequires:  python3dist(argparse)
#BuildRequires:  python3dist(ipaddress)
#BuildRequires:  python3dist(datetime)
BuildRequires:  python3-pip

Requires: python3
#Requires: python3-jinja2
#Requires: python3-datetime
#Requires: python3-requests
#Requires:  python3dist(jinja2)
#Requires:  python3dist(ipaddress)
#Requires:  python3dist(datetime)
Requires:  python3-pip


#%{?python_disable_dependency_generator}
%?python_enable_dependency_generator

%description
network administration module


%prep
%autosetup -n %{srcname}-%{version}
# Adding netlodrd group
getent group netlord || groupadd netlord

%build
%py3_build

%install
%py3_install
cp -r %{_sourcedir}/%{srcname}-%{version}/var %{buildroot}
cp -r %{_sourcedir}/%{srcname}-%{version}/etc %{buildroot}


%files 
/usr/bin/netlord-check-config
/usr/bin/netlord-update-db
%attr(0775, root, netlord) %{_sysconfdir}/netlord/config
%attr(4775, root, netlord) /var/netlord
%{python3_sitelib}/%{srcname}-*.egg-info/
%{python3_sitelib}/%{srcname}/
```

rpm собирается успешно, но при запуске модуля возникают ошибки свидетельствующие о том что у меня не установлены соответствующие модули. Что весьма логично, поскольку я закомментировал строки c Requires.

Если их раскомментировать то ничего не получится по 2-м причинам:

1. Строки типа:

```
Requires:  python3dist(ipaddress)
```

либо не смогут перевести эту запись в название rpm пакета, либо не найдут в репозиториях соответствующего пакета.

2. Строки типа:

```
Requires: python3-jinja2
```

просто не найдут нужного пакета.

Да, я вижу несколько очевидных байпасов:
добавить в `%prep` что то вроде `pip3 install jinja2`
или найти third-party репозитории с нужными пакетами и подключить их.
Но думаю что это скорее костыли чем решение.

В различных гайдах я нашёл 2 решения этой проблемы которые не сработали:
`%?python_enable_dependency_generator`
которой должен из .egg доставать все нужные зависимости и просто найти и указать всё в виде .rpm зависимостей что оказалось не сработает для стандартных репозиториев CentOS 7.

Ну и собственно сам вопрос: как добавить в rpm сторонние модули python3 при сборке собственного?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ "относительно" прост. Нужно создать отдельный пакет для *каждого* модуля, для которого нет пакета в предпочитаемых репозиториях.

Полагаю, что пакеты из EPEL не могут считаться костылём, соответственно, если пакет есть там, то свой создавать не нужно.

Из перечисленного вами, уже имеются:

```
Requires: python36-jinja2
Requires: python36-requests
```

Comment: А если у модуля, у которого нет пакета, есть в зависимостях ещё модули? Получается мне нужно и их упаковать в пакеты. Довольно трудоёмко. Странно что не существует более простого механизма.

Comment: Да, так и получается.  Теоретически можно упаковывать целый virtualenv, но это больше подходит для Python приложений и никак не для модулей/библиотек.